# Clases diccionarios y listas en python

Tags: python

Buenas noches estoy empezando en el mundo de python y estoy haciendo un simple programa de POO, el programa consta de una clase libro con los atributos nombre y autor y lo que quiero hacer es insertar varios libros y guradarlos en uina lista o diccionario para que me entiendan mejor les dejo lo que mas o menos quiero hacer en c++ y lo que tengo en python`

Parte del codigo de c++

```
void Libro :: ingresar(){
    string nombre;
    string autor;
    cout<<"Ingresar el nombre"<<endl;
    getline(cin, nombre);
    setNombre(nombre);
    cout<<"Ingresar el autor"<<endl;
    getline(cin, autor);
    setAutor(autor);
}
void Libro :: salir(){
    cout<<"Nombre: "<<getNombre()<<endl;
    cout<<"Autor: "<<getAutor()<<endl;
}



int main(){
    Libro libros[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        libros[i].ingresar();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        libros[i].salir();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Y esto es lo que tengo en python

```
class libro():
    def __init__(self, nombre, autor, libros):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.autor = autor   
        self.libros = []
    def add(self):
        self.nombre = input("Ingresar nombre: ")    
        self.autor = input("Ingrese autor: ")
    def mostrar(self):
        print("Nombre: ",self.nombre)
        print("Autor: ",self.autor)



obj = libro("","")
obj.add()
obj.mostrar()
```

Espero me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La forma más sencilla de resolver este caso es usando un diccionario. No es necesario inicializar el objeto con las dos cadenas vacías, ni tampoco es necesario hacer atributos el libro y el autor, ya que son variables que se van sobreescribiendo a medida que se va recorriendo el diccionario.
Este código te puede servir de referencia para lo que quieres.

```
class libro():
    def __init__(self):
        self.libros = {} #diccionario vacio
    def add(self):
        insert = True
        while insert:
            nombre = input("Ingresar nombre: ")    
            autor = input("Ingrese autor: ")
            self.libros[nombre] = autor # Agrega el elemento al diccionario
            print()
            if (input("Registrar otro libro? S/N: ")).lower() == "n":
                insert = False

    def mostrar(self):
        print()
        for nombre, autor in self.libros.items(): # .items() funciona en Python 3.x
            print("----")
            print("Nombre: {} - Autor: {}".format(nombre, autor))

obj = libro()
obj.add()
obj.mostrar()
```

Comment: Si tuviera mas de dos variables digamos nombre autor editorial y año_publicacion como se haria en ese caso, se utilizaria diccionarios o listas

Comment: Como era un poco larga, agregué una explicación a tu duda como otra respuesta en esta misma pregunta. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Las listas, tuplas, diccionarios y conjuntos son estructuras de datos muy poderosas y versátiles en Python. Cuando las sepas usar bien, junto con otras instrucciones de alto nivel (map, filter, lambda, etc...) las vas a amar.
Se pueden hacer arreglos de diccionarios para permitir la entrada de más datos correspondiente a un valor índice.
Por ejemplo:

```
libros = {
"Cien años de soledad": ["Gabriel García Marquez", "Editorial 01", 1982], 
"Don quijote de la Mancha" : ["Miguel de Cervantes", "Editorial 02", 1600], 
"El Principito" : ["Antoine De Saint Exupery", "Editorial 03", 1943]}

print(libros["Don quijote de la Mancha"][2])
```

Salida:

> 1600

Sin embargo, en este caso particular, es menos intuitivo trabajar con los índices numéricos de las listas. Es más versátil los índices alfanuméricos de los diccionarios, los cuales puedes actualizar o agregar en el momento que quieras. El diccionario tendrá un comportamiento muy similar a los JSON.
Ejemplo:

```
libros = {
"Cien años de soledad": {"Autor":"Gabriel García Marquez", "Editorial":"Editorial 01", "Anio":1982 }, 
"Don quijote de la Mancha" : {"Autor":"Miguel de Cervantes", "Editorial":"Editorial 02", "Anio":1600}, 
"El Principito" : {"Autor":"Antoine De Saint Exupery", "Editorial":"Editorial 03", "Anio":1943}}

print(libros["El Principito"]["Autor"])
print(libros["El Principito"]["Editorial"])
print(libros["El Principito"]["Anio"])
```

Salida:

> Antoine De Saint Exupery
>
> Editorial 03
>
> 1943

Suponiendo que quieres agregar 2 elementos más al arreglo del ejemplo anterior:

```
libros["Los miserables"] = { "Autor":"Victor Hugo", "Editorial":"Editorial 04", "Anio":1862 }
libros["Orgullo y prejuicio"] = { "Autor":"Jane Austen", "Editorial":"Editorial 01" }
# intencionalmente no se puso el año para agregarlo en la siguiente línea.
libros["Orgullo y prejuicio"]["Anio"] = 1813
```

Si quieres imprimir todos los datos del arreglo

```
for nombre, valor in libros.items():
    autor = valor["Autor"]
    editorial = valor["Editorial"]
    anio = valor["Anio"]
    print("Nombre: {} - A: {} | E: {} | Año: {}".format(nombre, autor, editorial, anio))
```

La salida es:

> Nombre: Cien años de soledad - A: Gabriel García Marquez | E: Editorial 01 | Año: 1982
>
> Nombre: Don quijote de la Mancha - A: Miguel de Cervantes | E: Editorial 02 | Año: 1600
>
> Nombre: El Principito - A: Antoine De Saint Exupery | E: Editorial 03 | Año: 1943
>
> Nombre: Los miserables - A: Victor Hugo | E: Editorial 04 | Año: 1862
>
> Nombre: Orgullo y prejuicio - A: Jane Austen | E: Editorial 01 | Año: 1813

Finalizando, se puede modificar el código de la respuesta anterior para integrar las nuevas características. Y una forma de hacerlo podría ser la siguiente:

```
class libro():
    def __init__(self):
        self.libros = {} #diccionario vacio
    def add(self):
        insert = True
        while insert:
            nombre = input("Ingresar nombre: ")    
            autor = input("Ingrese autor: ")
            editorial = input("Ingrese Editorial: ")
            anio = input("Ingrese año: ")
            lib_atributos = { "Autor":autor, "Editorial":editorial, "Anio":anio }
            self.libros[nombre] = lib_atributos # Agrega el elemento al diccionario
            print()
            if (input("Registrar otro libro? S/N: ")).lower() == "n":
                insert = False

    def mostrar(self):
        print()
        for nombre, valor in self.libros.items(): # .items() funciona en Python 3.x
            print("----")
            autor = valor["Autor"]
            editorial = valor["Editorial"]
            anio = valor["Anio"]
            print("Nombre: {} - A: {} | E: {} | Año: {}".format(nombre, autor, editorial, anio))

obj = libro()
obj.add()
obj.mostrar()
```